# what is the meaning of (.atmx) stand for in Robotics Process Automation

Tags: automationanywhere

what is the **abbreviation** of **`.atmx`**

*automation anywhere* tool in **Robotics Process Automation** ?

Comment: I googled a bit and found `Asynchroner Transfer Modus eXchange` which I doubt is the correct answer. But does it matter? They also create the extension `.mbot` for metabots. The reason for any extension is for the program using them to recognize them and understanding HOW to interpret them.

Comment: ".atmx" is the extension for "Automation Anywhere Task File". I agree with Roel Strolenberg, extension does not matter, that is to recognize file and understanding how to interpret it.